# Retrieved list of videos does not match YouTube results -- not a caching issue?

Tags: youtube-api

I am working with the YouTube API's ability to capture a list of videos. I am curious as to why the response from the API does not match-up with what I see on YouTube. I have read the reference material https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference and I do not believe this to be a caching issue as the videos in question are years old.

As an example, consider the following link: http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Gramatik

The top 10 results returned:

- Just Jammin
- So Much For Love
- Muy Tranquilo
- Orchestrated Incident
- Liquified
- While I Was Playin' Fair
- Solidified
- Defying Gravity
- Still Night (Gramatik Remix)
- So Much For Love (again, different video thougH)

By contrast, consider the following API query: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=Gramatik&alt=json&prettyprint=true

The top 10 results:

- Just Jammin'
- So Much For Love
- Muy Tranquilo
- Liquified
- While I Was Playin' Fair
- Solidified
- Still Night (Gramatik Remix)
- So Much For Love (different)
- Hit That Jive
- Knight of Cydonia (Gramatik Remix)

Why the discrepancy? As far as I can tell my query should return identical results.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I can confirm your results ... my experiments did the same. You may have hit on the fact that the website uses a slightly different algorithm than the one exposed through the data webservice. I tried with v2 of the API rather than just v1, and my results were slightly different from both of yours. I just requested access to the private beta of v3, and if it's granted we can see if it offers a fourth permutation or if it's the same as the website (i.e. youtube.com could have already implemented the algorithms lying underneath the on-the-horizon API).

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this! I had not considered the fact that different versions of their API would be releasing different information. Very interesting! Do let me know if you get access to v3. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The services are slightly different.  The signals are weighted differently for each service. You should expect to have the top videos be the same.